# MySQL - Count rows by adding number of days to the base date, both stored in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database structure:

[image: Table Structure]

I have to count numbers of rows which have elapsed their returning date and haven't returned their book, example: `id` 12 haven't returned the book after the prescribed date.

This will be calculated like: `issued_on`(datetime) + `duration` (in days) should be greater than present date will be counted.

In my case, if book  is not returned then `returned_on` will be NULL and `status` will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tableName WHERE (issued_on+duration)<CURDATE() AND returned_on EQUALS NULL AND status EQUALS 1
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `library_issue` WHERE (`issued_on`+`duration`)<CURDATE() AND `returned_on` IS NULL AND `status` = 1 Shows 0 count, but it should show 1 in above case

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `library_issue` WHERE ADDDATE(issued_on, interval duration day) > CURDATE() AND status = 0 AND returned_on IS NULL